# Asynchronous image download inside a cell without knowing the height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, objective-c-blocks

I'm facing this problem and I've been trying to figure out how to fix it but without success. 
I have a table view with cells that contain an image which I still don't know which height is going to be. I created an outlet to the height constraint of the imageView and I'm downloading the image asynchronous with PinRemoteImage (I can use `SDWebImage` too but I think it's buggy in iOS 9). Inside the blocks is where I assign the new constant for the height constraint and then I do a layout update. 
The cell never updates, the only way I can see the image correctly is scrolling down and then up (when the tableview repaints the cell)

```
__weak typeof(UITableView*) weakTable = tableView;
__weak typeof(NSIndexPath*) index = indexPath;

[cell.commentImageView pin_setImageFromURL:[[CTImageHelper sharedInstance] resizedImageURLConverterFromStringWithPrefix:comment.image.completePath andOptions:optionsString] completion:^(PINRemoteImageManagerResult *result) {
   CommentTableViewCell *cellToUpdate = [weakTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
   cellToUpdate.heightSize = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:result.image.size.height/2];
   cellToUpdate.commentImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = result.image.size.height/2;
        [cellToUpdate setNeedsLayout];
}];
```

This is the code for setting the table view row height automatically

```
self.postTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 244.0;
self.postTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

And an image about the cell constraints:
[image]

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Don't give height constraint to imageview. Update this cell when image is download. The cell should grow automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `layoutIfNeeded` just after `setNeedsLayout`

```
 [cellToUpdate setNeedsLayout];
 [cellToUpdate layoutIfNeeded];

 // and then tell the tableView to update.
 [weakTable beginUpdates];
 [weakTable endUpdates];
 // then scroll to the current indexPath
 [weakTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone 
                         animated:NO];
```

**Update**   `[weakTable beginUpdates];[weakTable endUpdates];` might crash if call it more than once at a time. you need to make sure there is no colision between them.

You may also try just reloading the cell itself.

```
 [cellToUpdate setNeedsLayout];
 [cellToUpdate layoutIfNeeded];
 [weakTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: I added it and still not refreshing it :/

Comment: how do you change the cell height it self? what does `heightSize` do? or how you use it?

Comment: heightSize is a property that keeps the final image height

Comment: So how do you change the cell height? or it's calculated dynamicly?

Comment: @JoanCardona   
 
So how do you change the cell height? or it's calculated dynamicly?

Comment: I know the image height when the image is downloaded. The UIImageView has a fixed height constraint (initially is 0) and when the image is downloaded I change this constraint cellToUpdate.commentImageViewHeightConstraint.constant
Autolayout should do the job of resizing the whole cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101701/discussion-between-ismail-and-joan-cardona).

Answer (score 1):

You should call `layoutIfNeeded` after calling `setNeedsLayout` to actually trigger the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the tableview that the height has changed on it's cells by triggering an empty update, apart from the `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: tableview behaves really weird and then crashes. Any idea?

Comment: Out of bounds: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 12 beyond bounds for empty array.
It only happens with this, the array looks good when I don't have this lines

Comment: Can you modify your question to include the relevant sections where you use/set that array? Do you call the table view on the main thread?